# How not to effect adjacent elements when hovering over a element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement workflowy bullet points using html and CSS, I have used hover to add border to a div but it affects, nearby elements, any hint to avoid this will be appreciated?

```
.bullets {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bullets:hover {
  border: 5px solid lightgrey;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.bulletChild {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="bullets"></div>
    <p>this is workflowy clone</p>
    <div class="bulletChild">
      <div class="bullets"></div>
      <p>this is workflowy clone</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/renx777/mwvx8zdz/3/

Comment: Nothing happens when I hover over anything in the snippet you've provided, since the elements with the `bullets` class are empty. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Keep the border around the bullet at all times, but make it transparent in the non-hover state. This will prevent any shifting on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use UL or OL tags for lists.

But considering your current HTML, instead of using border, you can use box-shadow:

```css
.bullets {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  background-color:grey;
  border-radius:50%; 
}

.bullets:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black;
}

p {
  display:inline;
  margin-left:5px;
}


.bulletChild {
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  
  <div class="block">
    <div class="bullets"></div>
    <p>this is workflowy clone</p>
    <div class="bulletChild">
      <div class="bullets"></div>
      <p>this is workflowy clone</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```